Get Score as a float value from Mediapipe detection score
I am trying to take mediapipes detection.score as a float value, however, I am unsure how to convert it to that. I am trying to compare detection.score with a float number. Check code below:
imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
self.results = self.faceDetection.process(imgRGB)

bboxs = []

if self.results.detections:
    for id, detection in enumerate(self.results.detections):

        #Creating the rectangle for drawing
        bboxC = detection.location_data.relative_bounding_box
        imgH, imgW, imgC = frame.shape
        bbox = int(bboxC.xmin * imgW), int(bboxC.ymin * imgH), \
               int(bboxC.width * imgW), int(bboxC.height * imgH)
        
        bboxs.append([bbox, detection.score])

        if draw:
            cv2.rectangle(frame, bbox, (255, 0, 255), 2)
            cv2.putText(frame, f'{int(detection.score[0]*100)}%', 
                (bbox[0], bbox[1]-20), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN,
                2, (255, 0, 255), 2)
            

        print(type(detection.score))

        if detection.score > 0.95:
            #print("Good image")
        else:
            #print("Bad image")

The print for the type of detection.score outputs as: <class 'google.protobuf.pyext._message.RepeatedScalarContainer'>. I am trying to convert this to a float value.
Tried using float(detection.score). Tried looking through documentation, but could not find anything.

RepeatedScalarContainer is a collection of values, not a single value. You can iterate over it, or convert it to a list.

Maybe you can also index it: float(detection.score[0])

Yes, indexing it correctly does what I need. I did not know it was a collection of values. Thank you!

The clue is "Repeated" in the type name
